# Remove strange characters from .mdb field names

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc

I have a large number of .mdb-files (as in Microsoft Access db-files). The first field (or column) is supposed be named say `MyField1`. However the files are corrupted so that the actual field name is `\ufeffMyField1` or in other words there is `0xFEFF`prepended to the actual field name.

I'm trying to copy the field in question from `\ufeffMyField1` to `NewField` using the pyodbc-command

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET NewField=" + colname + ";")
```

where `colname`is the errouneous field name (assume that `NewField`already exists)

The value of `colname` is fetched with pyodbc using something like

```
rows = cur.columns(table='MyTable')
for row in rows:
   if("MyField1" in row.column_name):
      colname=row.column_name
```

Executing the `UPDATE...` command yields a driver error that the MaxLocksPerFile Ms Access parameter is too low, as described here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815281/-file-sharing-lock-count-exceeded-error-message-during-large-transacti.
However I've increased the MaxLocksPerFile parameter with several orders of magnitude while opening only a single file in the program, so it seems it is not the actual problem.

Note that without problem I can open the file in MS Access and rename the field in the gui. I have not found a way to see in the gui that the field is incorrectly named, supposedly since the extra bits doesn't match common encodings.

Finally this leads me to my question: how can I pass raw bytes as pyodbc-commands?

Alternatively please suggest in comments if you have other ways to solve the real-world problem of removing the extra characters? (as in clean out all non-ASCII characters from the field names)

Comment: I'd try to use COM and DAO to rename columns. I doubt this is possible through SQL and ODBC, since you possibly can't refer to a field by an invalid name. You can try to bracket `[ ]` the field name, though, to account for the non-text characters, and see if that does it.

Comment: I don't have an .mdb file here, but have you checked if the string of the column names appears in the raw binary of the file so that you could simply just replace it there?

Comment: I've checked and haven't found them in a way connected to the field names. Not spent enough time on that to say conclusively though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use DAO, then it is pretty simple.  You can modify the following code to find and loop thru a folder of all databases.

```
Sub Rename_First_Field()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\....\SomeDB.mdb")
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs           ' Spin thru all tables in this database
        Set fld = tdf.Fields(0)             ' Grab the first field
        Debug.Print tdf.Name & vbTab & "|" & vbTab & fld.Name
        fld.Name = "MyField1"               ' Rename to 'MyField1'
    Next tdf                                'Move to next table
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not python code. My suggestion was invoking DAO from Python using COM and PyWin32. Using VBA, it's much easier, of course.